# Creating a reusable component with scalatags

Tags: scala.js, scalatags

I'd like to create a reusable component with **scalatags** like this one:

```
<div class="container">
  <button>Delete me</button>
  <div class="actual-content">
    ...
  </div> 
</div>
```

and I'd like to register an `onclick` listener to the button which deletes the whole `div` container when clicked.

I know that I can do something like this (with jQuery):

```
div(id:="myid")(
  button(onclick:={() => jQuery("#myid").remove()}(Delete me),
  div(...)
)
```

but the problem with this solution is that I'm generating this element automatically and getting the element by id is cumbersome because I'd have to generate unique ids.

Is there a better way? Is there a way to reference a 'myid' `div` from inside the div?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM Event callbacks (e.g. what you pass to `onClick := ???`) receive an instance of an `Event` as their first parameter. That event has a `target` property that contains the `Node` which the event was triggered on (in your case, that would be the button being clicked). That node has a `parentNode` property which refers to the parent node (element) of the target element. In your case the button's `parentNode` is your div, the node you want to remove. So you could provide this kind of callback to remove the div:

```
def clickHandler = (event: Event): Unit = {
  val myDiv = event.target.parentNode
  myDiv.parentNode.removeChild(myDiv)
}
```

However, you should know that this style of UI programming is very imperative and does not scale well to a bigger codebases. There are better ways to write frontend apps nowadays. For Scala.js for example there are a few libraries for managing DOM state:

- Interfaces to React.js, a popular JS library ([SRI](https://github.com/chandu0101/sri) or [scalajs-react](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react) or [react4s](https://github.com/Ahnfelt/react4s))
- [Scalatags-rx](https://github.com/rtimush/scalatags-rx)
- [Binding.scala](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala)

There are more, these are just the ones that I remember right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a simple answer for this one, I'm afraid, but here's some food for thought.

Personally, I wound up building a fairly elaborate framework, to deal with this issue among others. That introduces a notion that I wound up calling a [GadgetRef](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/display/rx/GadgetRef.scala), which encapsulates a Scala.Rx Var that references a Scalatags node, outside of the Scalatags tree, and gets set to the actual node when it is created.

So for example, [this page](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/apps/ExtractAppPage.scala) [defines an Input field in one place](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/apps/ExtractAppPage.scala#L37), [sets it inside the Scalatags tree](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/apps/ExtractAppPage.scala#L68-L70), and [references it in other places](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/apps/ExtractAppPage.scala#L41-L45).

That's a fairly elaborate framework, though, which isn't yet extracted into a separate library. So it's an idea, but not a silver-bullet answer to the problem...